# How to Nest Multiple Observables/Subscriptions

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs

## 1. The Problem

I'm trying to create a flow of changing language for my blog and, in sum, this is how it would look like:

1. The user clicks a button that triggers an event (`Subject`), i.e., the language change.
2. This language change is used to query `Firebase` for the correct page based on that language.

If I do each step separately and, later, the user changes the language, then the query won't be triggered because it doesn't know an event has just happened. So I believe this should be some sort of nested subscription/observable. Am I wrong?

## 2. My Code So Far

I've tried nesting subscriptions, but it didn't work. I believe it was because of scoping bugs. Right now, this is what I'm trying:

```js
this.headerService.langChanged.pipe(
  map(
    (newLang: string) => {
      this.db
        .collection<AboutMePage>(
          this.aboutMeCollectionName, 
          ref => ref.where('lang', '==', newLang)
        )
        .valueChanges();
  })
)
  .subscribe(
    value => {
      this.aboutMe = value[0]
    }
  );
```

The `headerService.langChanged` is a `Subject<string>`.

Is there an `rxjs` operator for this use case? `concat` seemed like a good candidate, but it would have wait for the previous `Observable` to end, which it doesn't in this case. And there's also the fact that I have to pass parameters onto the next observable...

Comment: Try `switchMap()` it will makes API call and request new observable each time input language is changed.

Comment: Why do you have `take(1)`? It sounds like you do want to listen for more than just the first event

Comment: @Freddy, well spotted. That was probably a reminiscent of my many attemps at making this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's valid solutions for you using any of `concat`, `switchMap`, `merge`, `forkJoin`, etc. It really depends on the small things that you want out of them such as concurrency. I put together a little Stackblitz example using `forkJoin` here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyf8a6

You can see in the console logs the different timings of each inner `Observable` to verify that using `forkJoin` has it so that it'll only take as long as the slowest observable.

And the subscription as I have it:

```js
this.langChanged
  .subscribe(newLang => {
    console.log(`language changed ${newLang}`);
    this.cancelLangChange.next();
    forkJoin(
      this.getUserName(newLang), 
      this.getUserBio(newLang), 
      this.getUserCreationDate(newLang)
    )
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.cancelLangChange))
      .subscribe(([username, bio, userCreationDate]) => {
        this.aboutMe.username = username;
        this.aboutMe.bio = bio;
        this.aboutMe.userCreationDate = userCreationDate;
      });
  });
```

I also added a second `Subject` `cancelLangChange` which is meant to cancel the `forkJoin` subscriptions if a user selects another language while it is still loading the first change.

Comment: A little bit before you posted this answer I had just managed to make it work here. I used `pipe` and `map` to have the language observable return me another observable every time the language changes; then I subscribe to it, and, inside, I subscribe to the returned observable. (Sounds more complicated than the code itself...) Do you see any problems with my solution? (I do unsubscribe to both subscriptions on `ngOnDestroy`.)

Comment: Nothing major, that should be fine. Only concern I'd have is if it was possible for the user to change the language twice and the second Observable finishes before the first. You could end up with the first's data in the end. But that scenario is probably unlikely anyway.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, but also post mine later.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by using `pipe` and `map` basically. The `map` operation will use the first observable to generate another one based on the former's parameters. Then we subscribe in a nested manner, which will finally give us the data we wanted.

```js
this.aboutMeSubscription = this.headerService.langChanged.pipe(
  map(
    (newLang: string) => {
      return this.db
        .collection<AboutMePage>(
          this.aboutMeCollectionName, 
          ref => ref.where('lang', '==', newLang)
        )
        .valueChanges();
  })
)
  .subscribe(
    langChangedAboutMeObs => {
      this.langChangedSubscription = langChangedAboutMeObs
        .subscribe(
          (value: AboutMePage[]) => {
            this.aboutMe = value[0];
          }
        );
    }
  );
```

I also changed my `Subject` to a `BehaviorSubject` so an initial value has been emitted even before the user does anything. Lastly, it's important to unsubscribe to both subscriptions on `ngOnDestroy`.